# angular currency pipe, what are the locale options?

Tags: angular

I am using angular's currency pipe, and I was wondering if there's some list that contain all the optional locales and currencies.

Currently I am trying to switch the locale to `il-he` and the currency to `NIS`
And It seems to not be supported...

I will be happy to get some link that will display the supported currencies and maybe a way to add new currency to the list.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found out that, locale are based on: [BCP47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) and the currency taken from [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)